# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000002ef (code=0) while using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, sigabrt, android-webservice

Application sometimes crashes when calling API with retrofit and doing some UI interactions. I'm using Retrofit version 1.7.0.

Logcat shows:

```
I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000002ef (code=0), thread 8653
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Enable `Show all ANR`s in developer options and look what causes the ANR in  `/data/anr/traces.txt`

Comment: How to get /data/anr/traces.txt on a device without root access?